# How to read a file without extension in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, plist, file-read

I have a file stored in my iOS App Documents directory. It is a plist file but without .plist file extension. I want to read its content from code but i cant open the file without extension. Is there any way to add plist extension or convert the file into plist, or any way to read content of a file without extension.

This is how my code look like

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.bookmarks"];
filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

Thanks in Advance

PS : If I add the .plist extension in finder(by some method) I can open the file and see the content. So I am sure about its type.

Comment: Try giving empty extension ??

Comment: I tried giving null extension. I have path to file in NSString variable. can I add the .plist extension any how? or any other help.

Comment: Try giving empty string as extension. Tried that ?

Comment: Which method are you trying to use ?

Comment: I have posted the code. Still the *dic is showing nil.

Comment: You have marked the one answer to your question as correct but have commented here more recently.  Did the answer solve your question?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];` line completely?  If the Plist file doesn't have an extension on the file system then you shouldn't be adding an extension to the file path. If you call `[filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@""]` it will add a `.` to the filename which is probably not what you want.

Comment: The answer is working fine.Thanks guys for your support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible to load the Plist file whether it has a `.plist` extension or not.  Assuming the Plist filename is `sample.bookmarks` then the following should load the Plist. I am assuming the root element of the Plist is a dictionary because you state that the Plist can be opened if it has a `.plist` extension.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sample.bookmarks"];
NSDictionary *dict=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

The only change is that I've removed the line that adds a `plist` extension to the `filePath`.

The `filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];` line will change the filename portion of the `filePath` to `sample.bookmarks.plist`.  If you changed the extension to an empty string (`filePath = [filePath stringByAppendingPathExtension:@""];`) then the filename will be changed to `sample.bookmarks.` which is not the same as `sample.bookmarks`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

```
pathToFile = [pathToFile stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"plist"];
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will check with this